# Pycharm IDE tries to load django script from sh instead of bash

Tags: python, django, macos, pycharm

If i try to compile messages in Django I get erros like this:

```
sh: msgfmt: command not found
```

while from bash (terminal) all these commands work fine.. How do I change Pycharm to run these commands from bash instead of sh ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually PyCharm itself doesn't use either sh or bash to run these commands; it runs the manage.py Python script using the interpreter configured in Settings | Python Interpreters. The compilemessages command uses os.system() Python function to run the msgfmt command. The os.system() function runs the system() C function, which always uses /bin/sh.

Therefore, you need to configure your OS in such a way that msgfmt could be run from /bin/sh.

Comment: thanks, is this possible with a system link? I have no real experience with these matters

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by installing `gettext` tool, in debian/ubuntu you can execute `sudo apt-get install gettext`, for windows is explained in [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows).

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785138/2343488) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8040885/2343488) for others SO and explanations.

I got the same error message but from other cause and solve it in this way.