# django translation: msgfmt: command not found

Tags: django, translation

I have installed OSQA using the wiki script (webfaction). Now I want to compile a message file and I get the following error:

```
django msgfmt command not found
```

The command + output:

```
$ ls
apache2 bin lib osqa osqa.wsgi wfinstall.log

[rijkers@web303 hozburo]$ cd osqa
[rijkers@web303 osqa]$ ../bin/django-admin.py compilemessages
processing file django.po in /home/rijkers/webapps/hozburo/osqa/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES sh: msgfmt: command not found
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`msgfmt` is a program. You need to have it installed on your system for this compilemessages command to work (at least as far as I know it).

You are probably on some *nix system, so it shouldn't be very hard. Just use your package manager and install `gettext` package (or similar).

Comment: thanks, my hosting provider admitted that it is by mistake not on the server so that is the issue indeed.

Comment: Similar solution for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8784974/2343488) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6882387/2343488) answers