# Django 1.3.1 compilemessages. Error: sh: msgfmt: command not found

Tags: django, osx-lion

```
./manage.py compilemessages
```

throws this error:

```
sh: msgfmt: command not found
```

I am running Mac OS 10.7, and I can't find the download path for the msgfmt program. Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[update] TLDR; as Dogukan commented: Mac OS Maverics `brew install gettext; brew link gettext --force` worked for me.

[update] user Lajarre reported: as of today (March 2014), I had to do `brew install msgpack`.

You need GNU gettext and gettext-tools.

If you use fink, try:

```
sudo fink install gettext-tools
```

You may need to add `/sw/bin/` to your PATH if it is not there yet.

If you don't use fink, try brew:

```
brew install gettext
brew link gettext
```

[update] removed sudo call from the brew example as suggested by Dave and Jason.

Comment: Brew is specifically designed *not* to be used under `sudo`; see [Why does Homebrew say sudo is bad?](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ#wiki-sudo).

Comment: Similar solution for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8040826/2343488) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6882387/2343488) answers

Comment: as of today, I had to do `brew install msgpack`

Comment: Mac OS Maverics brew install gettext, brew link gettext --force worked for me

Comment: brew install and force-link still works on macOS Sierra

Comment: I find it hard to believe you really need http://msgpack.org/ for this (which is what `brew install msgpack` will give you)

Answer (score 1):

Paulo Scardine's answer is perfect, but after I executed 'sudo brew link gettext' I got an error message.

> Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link'
> You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
> However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
> your own risk.

It's easy to handle it, just remove 'sudo'

> brew install gettext
>
> brew link gettext