# Unable to run configure for Mono Develop due to intltools

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop

I downloaded the latest version of [MonoDevelop Unity](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/monodevelop) from Git. Prior to this I tried the same with the vanilla version of [MonoDevelop](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop) from Git.

I have tried compiling MonoDevelop with the following: `./configure`

I tried both including and not including all packages:

```
Select the packages to include in the build for the profile 'default':

1. [X] main
2. [X] extras/JavaBinding
3. [X] extras/ValaBinding
4. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.Database
5. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb
6. [X] extras/PyBinding
7. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.MonoMac
8. [X] extras/MonoDevelop.MeeGo
```

I began to think to myself "This is going great!". Then came the roadblock:

```
Configuring package: main
-------------------------
Configuration options: 
Running aclocal  ...
Running automake --foreign  ...
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-compile-warnings --prefix=/usr/local ...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for gmcs... /usr/bin/gmcs
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for msgfmt... no
configure: error: You need to install msgfmt from intltool
```

I've tried my best in trying to manually install intltool, but I've experienced no luck in doing so.

How can this "configure error" be fixed? `configure: error: You need to install msgfmt from intltool`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I had to install `gettext` (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785138/282052)).

Comment: Not work for me.Install Mono and setting the PATH, works now. Thanks @mhutch

Comment: @Maadiah, did you downloaded from git or tarball sources?

Comment: From git.@AngelEscobedo

Answer (score 2):

If you're building MonoDevelop from source, you need the Mono MDK package, not the MRE package.

See http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support/Building_MonoDevelop_on_OS_X

Not sure about Unity's version, they maintain an old fork and I have no idea what they've changed.

Comment: I pulled a fresh copy on vanilla MonoDevelop and followed those steps, still getting "You need to install msgfmt from intltool". This happened upon typing "./configure --profile=mac" as the guide told me to. I also installed brew, pointed aclocal and such. I also installed the latest version of Mono (MDK) again.

Comment: Update: I even re-installed Mono again from scratch just then.

Comment: Thanks for the help nevertheless, I wouldn't have tried again if you didn't link me to the guide.

Comment: Does the file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/msgfmt not exist after installing the MDK?

Comment: It definitely didn't appear to be installed before I used brew to install it. I'll post an update if I am to re-install the MDK again.